# Docker image not running

Tags: docker, go

I've successfully built my docker image, so I'm trying to run it, I'm getting this error. This may sound stupid, but I'm not an expert in docker

[This is my Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZFGC.png)[This is the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96so3.png)

Pls if you can help me out. I also don't know how to use this stackoverflow to ask questions tho. Anyway you could understand what i'm saying, your response would be high appreciated

Comment: Do not use images. Include the source in your question. The output file is at the root directory, not under /app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build it, you put it in `/Portfolio_Backend`, but when you run it in the CMD statement, you run `/app/Portfolio_Backend`. That's why it can't find it.

What you want is probably to have the executable in the `app` directory, so change your build command to

```
RUN go build -o Portfolio_Backend
```

i.e. remove the leading slash in the name. Then it'll be in the `app` directory and it should work.

Also please note that posting images of text is frowned upon on Stack Overflow. The reason is that it's hard to copy/paste from your images for anyone that wants to try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Copy-paste isn’t the only issue. Images aren’t searchable, so, questions like this won’t pop up for someone having a similar problem.